# Where did Wonder Woman's sword come from?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice, wonder-woman

Now then, in Batman v Superman, we see that WW has a sword - this is a very special sword since it can

> pierce Kryptonian skin (namely doomsday's skin).

This means it's not a normal everyday sword - as that would likely get bent or broken when someone of WW strength

> hit it against Doomsday.

We know that it's not the same sword that was referred to as 'the God Killer' in Wonder Woman. That sword looked like this:
[image]

Whereas the sword in Batman v Superman had a handle like this:[image]

So, it's clear that they are different swords (this doesn't mention anything that **happens** in Wonder Woman).

> The sword gets destroyed in Wonder Woman.

So where does this sword come from? Did any of the writers/directors say anything? Anything from the comics indicate it's origin? Did I miss something in either WW or BvS?

Comment: There's 100 years between the events of WW and BvS....that's a lot room to play with.

Comment: http://collider.com/wonder-woman-god-killer-explained/#images

Comment: While this explains the God Killer sword, it *mentions* the sword of Athena. Could that be the sword she uses in B v S?

Comment: Fact is **we don't know**. It could be *any* sword that Diana has is imbued with magic just because she carries it.

Comment: The whole point was that **Diana** was the "God-killer"...not some magic sword or anything else.

Comment: I agree Paul, I guess I was asking in a comparison type way; as in do the characteristics that we've seen match the sword of athena. I'm not well versed in the comics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sword is mentioned as **Sword of Athena** in [dcmovies wikia](http://dcmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Sword_of_Athena)
and [dccomicsextendeduniverse wikia](http://dccomicsextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Sword_of_Athena).

Even on [dcextendeduniverse wikia](http://dcextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Sword_of_Athena) it say:

> The Sword of Athena[1](http://dcmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Sword_of_Athena) is a magically-empowered Amazonian sword wielded by Wonder Woman in battle, replacing the Godkiller sword after the latter was destroyed by Ares.
>
> Some time after World War I, Wonder Woman somehow acquired a replacement for Godkiller, the sword that Ares had destroyed.
>
> Wonder Woman would eventually proceed to wield the sword against Doomsday, managing to slice off the monster's right arm with it.

But none of those wikia have any  official source.

One of the trivial information we surely know about that sword is writing on it

[image]

> One such detail is the inscription that is found on Wonder Woman's (Gal Gadot) sword and shield. Director Zack Synder and Doug Harlocker spoke to a linguist and came up with a new language, all so they could inscribe a phrase from Joseph Campbell's book Goddesses: Mystery of the Feminine Divine. Snyder really liked the quote, and so had it etched into the blade.
>
> When translated, the quote states: "Life is killing all the time and so the goddess kills herself in the sacrifice of her own animal." [source: [comicbook.com](http://comicbook.com/dc/2016/04/19/engraving-on-wonder-womans-sword-in-batman-v-superman-revealed/)]

So I can't find any official source to confirm the name of the sword but it do seems like a strong magical sword which can cut a Kryptonian skin. So Wonder Woman must have got new sword before BvS which seems powerful enough and calling it Sword of Athena sound fine to me.

Answer (score 14):

The filmmakers have not said anything specific about where Diana gets her modern-day weapons, but keep in mind a few things:

- It's almost 100 years since the end of *Wonder Woman* and the beginning of *Dawn of Justice*, so she's had plenty of time.
- As we find out in the movie, there's *nothing really special* about the sword (at least, not in the way Diana thinks). In other words, it's most likely just an Amazonian sword put there as a decoy.

The simplest answer, though with no evidence to back it up, is that Diana just went back home and got another one, or had someone make her another one from the same material.

Comment: The weird thing is that while the *sword wasn't the God killer* (WW was), you could argue that her bracers **were** since that's what she uses to ultimately kill Ares. I do agree that in 100 years she could find another special sword.

Comment: I think the idea is that the sword, bracers, lasso, etc were just tools. In the hands of anyone else, they'd be useless. In the hands of Diana, they could kill a god. (In the comics, the bracers are made from Zeus's shield, but Diana's power lets her use them for more than just defense).

Comment: There was perhaps nothing special about the sword in *Wonder Woman*. The question itself goes into how we're pretty sure there **is** something special about the sword she had in *BvS*.